# Creating an AMI from Snapshot in AWS using Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want create an AMI from the snapshot that I currently have. I am using [ImportImageRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/ImportImageRequest.html) to accomplish the task. Following is my piece of code.

```
    ImportImageResult iir = ec2.importImage(new ImportImageRequest().withDiskContainers(new ImageDiskContainer().withSnapshotId("snap-3b4pd121")));
    System.out.println(iir.toString());
    System.out.println(iir.getImportTaskId());
    System.out.println(iir.getImageId());
```

The output comes out as

```
{ImportTaskId: import-ami-ffwthmw7,SnapshotDetails: [{DiskImageSize: 0.0,}],Progress: 2,StatusMessage: pending,Status: active}
import-ami-ffwthmw7
null
```

This means that the image Id is null. I am unable to deduce a reason for that. I also tried `describeImage()` to get more information but didn't find anything. It works for other images, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing an image takes a while. The call to `importImage` returns pretty quickly, but the background task to do the work is still running.

After you call `importImage`, call `describeImportImageTasks` to get the status on the background task. Find the `ImportImageTask` that you are interested in and look at `getStatus` and `getProgress` to see how things are progressing. Keep calling `describeImportImageTasks` until you see that the import has finished.

Once it is finished, all of the details about the result will be filled in.

When the AWS Java SDK documentation (e.g., javadoc) is woefully incomplete (as it is in this case), I find it useful to look at the docs for the corresponding command-line API calls. For [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/import-vm-image.html)

> Use the describe-import-image-tasks command to return the status of an
>   import task.
>
> Status values include the following:
>
> active — The import task is in progress.
>
> deleting — The import task is being canceled.
>
> deleted — The import task is canceled.
>
> completed — The import task is completed and the AMI is ready to use.